# Binding new calculated "sliding" data frames without using a loop and rbind

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have a `data.frame` with a `Date` column, and some other variables, e.g.:

```
df <- data.frame(date = rep(seq.Date(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2017-01-10"), by = "day"), 2),
             x = c(rep("a", 10), rep("b", 10)),
             y = rep(letters[3:7], each = 4),
             z = rnorm(20))
```

I wish to "slide" over the `Date`, calculating some new `data.frame` for each "window" of a certain width (say for all 3-day-length periods), then bind these into a new `data.frame`, say with some period "identifier" to know from which period each row came from, e.g. the first date of the period.

EXAMPLE, the not-pretty/slow way:

```
windowLength <- 3
dateVec <- df$date %>% unique %>% unlist

nonTrivialFunctionWhichCreatesANewDataFrame <- function(i) {
  df %>%
    filter(date >= dateVec[i], date <= dateVec[i + windowLength - 1]) %>%
    group_by(x, y) %>%
    summarise(zSum = sum(z), zCount = n()) %>%
    mutate(startDate = dateVec[i])
}

df2 <- NULL
for (i in 1:(length(dateVec) - windowLength + 1)) {
  dfTemp <- nonTrivialFunctionWhichCreatesANewDataFrame(i)
  df2 <- rbind(df2, dfTemp)
}

head(df2)

Source: local data frame [6 x 5]
Groups: x [2]

   x      y        zSum zCount  startDate
  <fctr> <fctr>       <dbl>  <int>     <date>
1      a      c  1.27899229      3 2017-01-01
2      b      e  1.05072378      2 2017-01-01
3      b      f -1.04083228      1 2017-01-01
4      a      c  0.67568894      3 2017-01-02
5      b      e  0.03046459      1 2017-01-02
6      b      f -1.55901277      2 2017-01-02
```

I've tried playing with `rollapply` from the `zoo` package, defining my `data.frame` as a time series object first - to no avail.

What is a faster and loop-less way to do this?

---

UPDATE: Why `zoo`'s `rollapply` doesn't work for me

Simple example:

```
z <- zoo(1:10, as.Date(rep(31:35, 2)))
z
1970-02-01 1970-02-01 1970-02-02 1970-02-02 1970-02-03 1970-02-03 1970-02-04 1970-02-04 1970-02-05 
     1          6          2          7          3          8          4          9          5 
1970-02-05 
    10

rollapply(z, width = 3, FUN = sum, align = "right")

1970-02-02 1970-02-02 1970-02-03 1970-02-03 1970-02-04 1970-02-04 1970-02-05 1970-02-05 
     9         15         12         18         15         21         18         24
```

As you can see, because the date is not unique, although `zoo` acknowledges that an re-arranges the data, the sum function rolls simply on 3 rows (1 + 6 + 2 = 9 for the first element) - not on 3 *days* as required!

Comment: Deleted my answer, will try and get a correct one using rollapply later.

Comment: Regading the UPDATE try aggregating the duplicate days down to a single day each and then run `rollsumr`: `library(zoo); 
DF <- data.frame(value = 1:10, index = as.Date(rep(31:35, 2)));
z <- read.zoo(DF, index = 2, aggregate = sum);
rollsumr(z, 3)`

Comment: Nice, but there's no need in this case to even use a time series object. See the original requirement which has a `nonTrivialFunctionWhichCreatesANewDataFrame` function involving a group_by and forming a whole new data.frame.